# $_GET['$something']; What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to build a universal postback system for a GPT script and well I am having just a bit of a problem.

I am not sure if what I am doing is allowed in PHP so that may be the problem, but this is what I got:

```
$ip = cleanQuery($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$getaffip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affiliates WHERE affip = '".$ip."' OR affip2 = '".$ip."' OR affip3 = '".$ip."' OR affip4 = '".$ip."'");
$affinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getaffip);

$affname = $affinfo['name'];
$campidi = $affinfo['campid'];
$subidi = $affinfo['subid'];
$ratei = $affinfo['rateid'];
$statusi = $affinfo['creditstatus'];
$credit = $affinfo['creditid'];
$reverse = $affinfo['reverseid'];

$subid = cleanQuery($_GET['$subidi']);
$rate = cleanQuery($_GET['$ratei']);
$status = cleanQuery($_GET['$statusi']);
$campid = cleanQuery($_GET['$campidi']);
```

what this means is it is pulling the variables that particular affiliate uses when they send the information to your postback, for example they would send this to the postback URL:

```
http://yoursite.com/postback/postback.php?campaignid=11546&yti=me&credit=1
```

the `$affinfo` fetches would pull the defined info that the particular affiliate sends like in the link above `$subidi` for the affiliate that posted it would be `yti` and `$campidi` would be `campaignid`, but the `$_GET` isn't pulling that information. It works if I change it to `$_GET['yti']`; in this case, but that wouldn't make it universal as all affiliates do not use the same variables when they send information to the postback script.

I am thinking that the `$_GET` doesn't support the `$values`, so what would be my best route of making it get the right information, or do I just have some kind of typo here that I have overlooked?

Comment: did you try using double quotes on the $_GET's with variables? Also I believe I read somewhere that this in fact may not be supported, but I havent done the research.

Comment: @ anybody who suggests changing them to double quotes: bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not quote the keys if they are variables:

```
$subid = cleanQuery($_GET[$subidi]);
$rate = cleanQuery($_GET[$ratei]);
$status = cleanQuery($_GET[$statusi]);
$campid = cleanQuery($_GET[$campidi]);
```

It would have worked if you had used double quotes instead of single, but that would be pointless and poor practice to needlessly quote variables.  The variables would have been interpolated inside the double quotes, ultimately giving the result you were after.

Answer (score 5):

Too many quotes :) Should be like this:

```
$subid = cleanQuery($_GET[$subidi]);
$rate = cleanQuery($_GET[$ratei]);
$status = cleanQuery($_GET[$statusi]);
$campid = cleanQuery($_GET[$campidi]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Variables in single quotes aren't evaluated. Double quotes are.

```
$foo = 'var';
echo 'my $foo'; // my $foo
echo "my $foo"; // my var
```

But you shouldn't be using any quotes in this situation